# Change CSS of cursor with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the CSS of the cursor to `default` on a `a href` link of `#` on the `menu-item-4082` "About" link below. And I don't know why this seemingly simple function doesn't want to work.

Must be something simple I'm not seeing. Is my CSS selector correct?

Or is there a different or better way to change the CSS with jQuery? What about removing the `href="#"` as well?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2nbad1gc/

**Function:**

```
$("li#menu-item-4082 .not-click").css("cursor","default");
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu-bar">
<li id="menu-item-217" class="menu-item">
    <a href="http://example.com/">Home</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-4082" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom
    menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4082
    has-dropdown not-click">
    <a href="#">About</a>
</li>
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li id="menu-item-158" class="menu-item menu-item-158">
        <a href="http://example.com/values/">Values</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-4083" class="menu-item menu-item-4083">
        <a href="http://example.com/why/">Why</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just to point out that you forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle, so it never would have worked, even with the fix provided by Josh.

Comment: @DrewKennedy: arrgg, you're right.... fixed.

Comment: basic css stylesheet rule would make this the easiest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is my CSS selector correct?

No, it's incorrect. It should be:

```
$("li#menu-item-4082.not-click a").css("cursor","default");
```

You were trying to select the child of `li#menu-item-4082` whose class is `not-click`. When in fact, the `li` itself had the class `.not-click`.

Remove the space between `$("li#menu-item-4082 .not-click")`.

As a side note, I'd suggest adding a class rather than adding inline CSS.

```
$("li#menu-item-4082.not-click a").addClass('default-cursor');
```

```
.default-cursor {
    cursor: default;
}
```

.. you could also remove the `href` attribute completely:

```
$("li#menu-item-4082.not-click a").removeAttr('href');
```

If you wanted to avoid jQuery completely, you could also remove the `href` attribute using plain JS:

Single element:

```
document.querySelector('#menu-main-menu-bar .not-click a').removeAttribute('href');
```

Multiple elements:

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('#menu-main-menu-bar .not-click a');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(anchors, function (el, i) {
    el.removeAttribute('href');
});
```

or you could avoid JS and just use CSS:

```
li#menu-item-4082.not-click a {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the exhaustive answer. What I eventually needed was the multiple elements function. But, the jQuery doesn't want to work in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2nbad1gc/28/ or the live site.  I loaded the live site CSS file in the fiddle, but it doesn't seem to be a CSS conflict that I can see. No console errors, either.

Comment: @songdogtech It appears to work in the fiddle you provided. http://jsfiddle.net/07bkgqvs/ It's worth pointing out that not all the `li` elements have the class `.not-click` as you can see, it was working for 2 of the elements.

Comment: Ah, you're right; Sunday morning confusion. OK, looks like something is broken on the live site, but no console errors, it's a mystery to me. But all your answers are correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your selector needs to be modified to

```
$('li#menu-item-4082.not-click a').css("cursor", "default");
```

Usually it is recommended to add a class to the HTML element that sets `cursor` to `default` rather than directly change the CSS with jQuery like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple css

```
.not-click a{
cursor: default;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2nbad1gc/14/